# How do I get the WordPress sidebar to show up on a post's detail page?

Tags: wordpress, sidebar, customizing

My example is [here](http://mtrainierphotos.com/blog/?p=7)

I am customizing the default template, but something isn't placed right. Can't figure it out.

By the way, I am asking this here and not at WordPress because frankly, their forums are horrible as far as response times go. Stackoverflow has always done me good :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the php code it'll be hard to know why. Do you have a seprate template for single post ie singlepost.php? If so, make sure you're include sidebar.php into that.

Looks like single.php in the default theme doesn't pull in the sidebar by default. You'll need to add `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>` right before `<?php get_footer(); ?>` in single.php or just delete the single.php and wordpress will use index.php instead which has the sidebar.

Comment: There is a "single.php" that i haven't modified, would that be it?

Comment: Yeah, make sure that pulling in the sidebar.php. Also look for any is_single() statements in your index.php that would prevent it from pulling in the sidebar. http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Comment: Ahhhh... there is no <?php get_sidebar(); ?> anywhere in this file. Where do you suggest I paste it in? Right inside the widecolumn?

Comment: Thanks, that was it :) I actually pasted it in right under get_header(); ?> and it worked. Just have to get the styling figured out. Thanks mucho BR ;)

Comment: You actually SHOULD put it before the footer, this way if there is an error i your sidebar code everything will load but the footer. This also follows the "standard" WordPress format. Also, as this is solved can you mark it as so?

Comment: I actually just deleted single.php and it looks much better using index. Thanks again!